# javascript - submitting button when changing text

Tags: javascript, otree

Im trying to change the text of a button (this button is part of a requiered form) and after that submitting the data from the button (on another button).
Im using:

```
$('label').mouseup( function() {
          var x = {{Arand|json}};
          $(this).addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-default').siblings().removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $(this).html(x);
        });
```

I also tried using "text" instead of html.

When I try to submit the button I get an error that I have to chose an option from the form - it appears that changing the text of the button also changed his value or it's abillity do hold the original value needed to be submited.

Is there a way of fixing this?